# Pipewire, Wireplumber, almost working like I want, but sound thru the center speaker only?

Tags: sound, hdmi

I was using Pulse for sound and had it working with great 5.1 surround sound. I could hear Angus Thunderstruck-ing all around me! But Jammy jammed me up, with the upgrade! (FYI: I do love this version) So with pipewire coming soon as default sound/video, I decided to make the move!

My issues:
(1) My machine shows it's seeing the surround, so cards, sinks, all that stuff is working (?), but all sounds comes from my center speaker! (I believe it's a simple fix-a mixing issue, but I'm lacking the smarts to fix it as I'm not much of a programmer).

(2) My configuration is Laptop>Hdmi-to>SonyDH550-Receiver(sound)>SamsungSmartTV (video). Before when I'd smart stream a movie (HDMI 1) or thru Firestick HDMI 2, the sound would play thru the receiver (DTH sound setup) with no issues! Now I have to set the TV to use the internal speakers to get sound when switching from HDMI1 (PC) to TV or HDMI2 (Firestick). It's almost like the pc is grabbing the HDMI and not letting the TV use it?
Setup Description:
for PC music
pc>HDMIout>ReciverHDMI1(in)>speakers>HDMI1out>TV(video)
Streaming:
SmartTV>HDMI1>receiver-HDMI2>speakers (firestick is on HDMI2 of TV

**Issue #1** is most important to me! FYI: I never change my configuration day to day (no headphone use). I almost always stream using the SmartTV apps or firestick, never thru PC. And Mr. Plant always sings to me from pc-HDMI-receiver-5.1 speakers!

A Big Thanks in Advance for any assistance, I appreciate you guys! Most times I can just read your posts and in doing so resolve my issues! Hope someone offers assistance, as Bonnie's "In The Mood" and I want her all around me! (^:

Info on current setup: (I apologize in advance for verbosity)

~$ systemctl --user status session.slice
● session.slice - User Core Session Slice
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/session.slice; static)
Active: active since Wed 2023-01-25 09:15:26 EST; 34min ago
Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
Tasks: 130
Memory: 505.5M
CPU: 3min 49.558s
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice
├─org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service
│ ├─2054 sh -c "/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable $([ "$XDG_>
│ ├─2061 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable
│ ├─2181 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
│ ├─2182 /usr/libexec/ibus-extension-gtk3
│ └─2221 /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simple
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.service
│ └─2055 /usr/libexec/gsd-a11y-settings
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color.service
│ └─2059 /usr/libexec/gsd-color
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime.service
│ └─2065 /usr/libexec/gsd-datetime
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.service
│ └─2066 /usr/libexec/gsd-housekeeping
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.service
│ └─2069 /usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service
│ └─2072 /usr/libexec/gsd-media-keys
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service
│ └─2073 /usr/libexec/gsd-power
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.service
│ ├─2074 /usr/libexec/gsd-print-notifications
│ └─2175 /usr/libexec/gsd-printer
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.service
│ └─2075 /usr/libexec/gsd-rfkill
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.service
│ └─2077 /usr/libexec/gsd-screensaver-proxy
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.service
│ └─2080 /usr/libexec/gsd-sharing
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.service
│ └─2085 /usr/libexec/gsd-smartcard
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.service
│ └─2095 /usr/libexec/gsd-sound
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom.service
│ └─2099 /usr/libexec/gsd-wacom
├─org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service
│ ├─6989 /usr/libexec/gsd-xsettings
│ └─7013 /usr/libexec/ibus-x11
├─org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service
│ ├─1935 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
│ ├─2432 gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com>
│ └─6982 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -a>
├─pipewire-pulse.service
│ └─1738 /usr/bin/pipewire-pulse
├─pipewire.service
│ └─1737 /usr/bin/pipewire
├─wireplumber.service
│ └─1741 /usr/bin/wireplumber
├─xdg-desktop-portal.service
│ └─2498 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal
└─xdg-document-portal.service
├─1770 /usr/libexec/xdg-document-portal
└─1784 fusermount3 -o rw,nosuid,nodev,fsname=portal,auto_unmount>

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD87B1/3 Analog [92HD87B1/3 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Bill:~$ aplay -L
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
Open Sound System
pipewire
PipeWire Sound Server
pulse
PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
default Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
Default Audio Device

surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers

surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
HDA Intel PCH, 92HD87B1/3 Analog
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers

---

$ dmesg | grep -iE "sound|snd|hda|codec|sof"

[    0.339663] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti giometti@linux.it
[    0.662509] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.662512] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x00000000d64ea000-0x00000000da4ea000] (64MB)
[   28.277799] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   29.449007] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for 92HD87B1/3: line_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   29.449015] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   29.449019] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   29.449023] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   29.449025] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   29.449027] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0xc
[   29.449029] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0xa
[   29.670149] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input25
[   29.670277] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input26
[   29.670370] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input27
[  126.540195] audit: type=1400 audit(1674655984.643:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" pid=1509 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  126.671454] audit: type=1400 audit(1674655984.775:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file" pid=1520 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  816.467018] audit: type=1326 audit(1674656674.572:79): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=3987 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/638/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f65b4f3573d code=0x50000
[ 1146.372093] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657004.481:117): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" pid=6384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1147.278809] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657005.385:120): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file" pid=6386 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 1850.157000] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657708.272:156): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="connect" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus" pid=8614 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1850.157227] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657708.272:157): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus" pid=8614 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 1850.157236] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657708.272:158): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_perm" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus" pid=8614 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2002.727720] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657860.844:159): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/zoneinfo64.res" pid=8614 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 2002.749657] audit: type=1400 audit(1674657860.864:160): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name="/usr/share/zoneinfo-icu/44/le/timezoneTypes.res" pid=8614 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

---

$ wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.48, Bill, cookie:979503940]
└─ Clients:
32. pipewire                            [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1738]
33. WirePlumber                         [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1741]
34. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1741]
60. GNOME Shell Volume Control          [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1935]
61. GNOME Volume Control Media Keys     [0.3.48, Bill, pid:2072]
62. xdg-desktop-portal                  [0.3.48, Bill, pid:2498]
63. Mutter                              [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1935]
64. spotify                             [0.3.48, Bill, pid:6887]
91. Firefox                             [0.3.48, Bill, pid:7258]
92. wpctl                               [0.3.48, Bill, pid:9047]
118. gnome-shell                         [0.3.48, Bill, pid:1935]
119. Firefox                             [0.3.48, Bill, pid:7258]

Audio
├─ Devices:
│      46. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
│
├─ Sinks:
│  *   49. Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) [vol: 0.40]
│
├─ Sink endpoints:
│
├─ Sources:
│  *   50. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.74]
│
├─ Source endpoints:
│
└─ Streams:
76. spotify
79. output_FC       > HDA Intel PCH:playback_FC
80. output_FR       > HDA Intel PCH:playback_FR
81. output_RL       > HDA Intel PCH:playback_RL
82. output_FL       > HDA Intel PCH:playback_FL
89. output_LFE      > HDA Intel PCH:playback_LFE
90. output_RR       > HDA Intel PCH:playback_RR

Video
├─ Devices:
│      41. Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_0.3M       [v4l2]
│      47. Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_0.3M       [v4l2]
│
├─ Sinks:
│
├─ Sink endpoints:
│
├─ Sources:
│  *   48. Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_0.3M
│
├─ Source endpoints:
│
└─ Streams:

Settings
└─ Default Configured Node Names:
0. Audio/Sink    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-surround

---

$ wpctl inspect 49
id 49, type PipeWire:Interface:Node
alsa.card = "0"
alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
alsa.class = "generic"
alsa.device = "3"
alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 29"
alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
alsa.subdevice = "0"
alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 29"
api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
api.alsa.path = "hdmi:0"
api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
audio.adapt.follower = ""
audio.channels = "6"
audio.position = "FL,FR,RL,RR,FC,LFE"
card.profile.device = "6"

- client.id = "34"
  clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
  device.api = "alsa"
  device.class = "sound"
- device.id = "46"
  device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
  device.profile.name = "hdmi-surround"
  device.routes = "1"
- factory.id = "18"
  factory.mode = "merge"
  factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
  library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
- media.class = "Audio/Sink"
- node.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)"
  node.driver = "true"
  node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
- node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-surround"
- node.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
  node.pause-on-idle = "false"
- object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hdmi:0:playback"
- object.serial = "50"
- priority.driver = "696"
- priority.session = "696"
  Bill:~$ wpctl inspect 50
  id 50, type PipeWire:Interface:Node
  alsa.card = "0"
  alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
  alsa.class = "generic"
  alsa.device = "0"
  alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
  alsa.id = "92HD87B1/3 Analog"
  alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 29"
  alsa.name = "92HD87B1/3 Analog"
  alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
  alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
  alsa.subdevice = "0"
  alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
  api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7e00000 irq 29"
  api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
  api.alsa.path = "front:0"
  api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
  api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
  audio.adapt.follower = ""
  audio.channels = "2"
  audio.position = "FL,FR"
  card.profile.device = "0"
- client.id = "34"
  clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
  device.api = "alsa"
  device.class = "sound"
- device.id = "46"
  device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
  device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
  device.routes = "2"
- factory.id = "18"
  factory.mode = "split"
  factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
  library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
- media.class = "Audio/Source"
- node.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
  node.driver = "true"
  node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
- node.name = "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
- node.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
  node.pause-on-idle = "false"
- object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:capture"
- object.serial = "51"
- priority.driver = "2009"
- priority.session = "2009"
  Bill:~$ wpctl inspect 76
  id 76, type PipeWire:Interface:Node
  adapt.follower.node = ""
  application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
- application.name = "spotify"
  application.process.binary = "spotify"
  application.process.host = "i8it"
  application.process.id = "6887"
  application.process.machine-id = "07237f22aad44b33b47ae5a5de303734"
  application.process.user = "bb"
  audio.adapt.follower = ""
  channelmix.lfe-cutoff = "140"
  channelmix.mix-lfe = "true"
  channelmix.upmix = "true"
  client.api = "pipewire-pulse"
- client.id = "64"
  clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
- factory.id = "6"
  factory.mode = "split"
  library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
- media.class = "Stream/Output/Audio"
  media.name = "Spotify"
- media.role = "Music"
  node.autoconnect = "true"
  node.latency = "8192/44100"
- node.name = "spotify"
  node.rate = "1/44100"
  object.register = "false"
- object.serial = "263"
  pulse.attr.maxlength = "4194304"
  pulse.attr.minreq = "7056"
  pulse.attr.prebuf = "0"
  pulse.attr.tlength = "640064"
  pulse.server.type = "unix"
  stream.is-live = "true"
  window.x11.display = ":0"

---

~$ pw-cli
Welcome to PipeWire version 0.3.48. Type 'help' for usage.

> > remote 0 is named 'pipewire-0'
> > Error: "unsupported type PipeWire:Interface:Profiler"

---

$ wireplumber
C 10:53:34.532795               GLib (null):(null):(null): Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted

Comment: Any takers? My TV issue resolved itself, (update?) but still all sound thru one speaker, even though pavucontrol shows 5 speakers-advanced all boxes checked. Found a dolby module by Wim that is .so format but I'm not clear on how to use it, yet! Any help would be appreciated. -Bill

Comment: Been fighting this issue 2 weeks now. Volume Control sees all 5.1 streams, system settings test sees 5 speakers, but only output F-C speaker. I know it's a simple answer for when looking at cmd to show various info shows 5.1 sound devices, drivers all there. But somewhere something is set to 1 output stream. Sure would appreciate a suggestion.